# How to install Ubuntu on HP stream 13?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, hp

I recently purchased HP Stream 13 for blogging and stuff, but it has very little space left plus windows 8.1 is full of bloatware. I was wondering how can I install complete Ubuntu 14 or Ubuntu 15; whichever is fully stable or something.

It has 32GB SSD and 2 GB ram.
Any help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a hp stream 11.. same as 13 but just smaller screen. I started with downloading and installing Ubuntu 14.04 onto a usb.

To boot the usb turn the hp stream on an press the Esc key to get into the boot order. Use the keyboard keys to navigate to the usb stick and hit enter.

When Ubuntu boots up you will need to hit Install and not try. When your going through the setup and get to the point where it asks if you want to install third party software (codecs ect) you will need to make sure this is clicked.

The reason for this is because it will not recognize your wifi card due to you needing to install the restricted third party software.

Once all is installed and you have booted up for the first time you will need to do a dist upgrade to get you onto Ubuntu 15.04

---

The only and i mean only problem i have experienced so far is that the wifi seems to be very unstable but after a bit of research i found out that you will need to install a different wifi driver :

[Click her to get Stable Wifi Driver](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new)

Download and  make install through terminal, then reboot Pc and Voila! Stable Wifi that never drops out.

Why Anyone would keep the bloated Windows 8.1 on these machines is shocking. Ubuntu 15.04 runs absolutely perfectly and the hardware is fully capable of maintaining a smooth performance even whilst watching 720p videos on Youtube,

Enjoy your new Ubuntu Machine!

Comment: I can still watch 1080p movies on my machine after Ubuntu, right?

Comment: The Hp Stream 11 and 13 are 1366 x 768 therefor only capable of 720p Videos.

Comment: It has windows pre installed and I watch 1080p and bluray movies without any hiccups..

Comment: It's pre installed with windows 8.1. Both the 11 and 13 are only 1366 x 768 so you are more than likely watching a 1080p movies scaled down to 720p. And yes it handles 720p just fine.